# Writing Cucumber features for accessing SVN

Tags: ruby, svn, mocking, cucumber

I'm developing a tool that accesses SVN by running the command line SVN to get info and export.

I'd like to write some Cucumber features so I don't have to keep manually testing but I'd like to mock out the SVN accesses.

1. Should I switch to using a Ruby SVN library and if so, which one?
2. Or is there a fake svn.exe that will provide programmable responses?

**EDIT:**

The tool takes a file path, finds the revision of parent URL a few levels up, then exports a bunch of files and folders at that revision into a new directory.  I'd like to write something like:

```
Given the file "extra1.txt" contains:
"""
extra1
"""

And the file "file.txt" contains:
"""
file
"""

And SVN holds the following files at revisions:
| tests/extras/extra1.txt    | 123 | extra1.txt |
| tests/path/part05/file.txt | 73  | file.txt   |

When I run "ruby dry_run_create c:\tests\path\part05\file.txt"

Then the file "c:\tests\path\part05\dry_run\extra1.txt" should contain:
"""
extra1
"""

And the file "c:\tests\path\part05\dry_run\file.txt" should contain:
"""
file
"""
```

With examples like these I could demonstrate forever more that the correct revisions were being extracted from SVN without having to actually create a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up looking and waiting and wrote my own, [MockVersion](http://github.com/bryan-ash/mockversion).

This provides some basic `svn` and `svnadmin` functionality so that I can create a mock repository with specific revisions and verify that those files are exported.

If anyone is interested in seeing more functionality, please open an [issue](http://github.com/bryan-ash/mockversion/issues) on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to actually test the SVN functionality, just mock out the calls completely.

Mocha is great for this

Check out (no pun intended) http://blog.floehopper.org/articles/2006/09/01/mocha-quickstart

Comment: thanks for the response.  I have specs that mock the calls at the lowest level.  I guess I'm looking for an end to end solution that is flexible enough that I can specify the SVN revisions of files.